# r data.table usage of .SD with multiple column sets to get RMSPE

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a data set where I have done some predictions. I now want to calculate the **RMSPE** and for this I am using the **MLmetrics** package as I understand by input of predicted and actual I would get the **RMSPE**. How ever I am confused how I can use this within **data.table** to pass 2 sets of columns.

My sample data set would look like something as below -

```
library(data.table)
library(MLmetrics)

set.seed(123)
id <- seq(1001,1100,1)
city <- sample(1:4,100,replace = T)
a1 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a2 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a3 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a4 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
a5 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p1 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p2 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p3 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p4 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)
p5 <- sample(1:100,100,replace = T)

df1 <- as.data.table(data.frame(id,city,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5))

RMSPE <- df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x,y) RMSPE(x,y),
                       by = city, .SDcols = **xxxx**)]
```

So in this case a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 are my actual values and p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 are my predicted values.I want to pass p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 as x and a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 as y. The resulting output that I am expecting is a kind of summary table with 4 rows ( one for each city) and 6 columns, 1st one for city, column 2-6 for **RMSPE** for each variable.

How can I get this in data.table. What should I replace *xxxx* with?

Thank you !!

Comment: @chinsoon12, this creates 20 rows with 2 variables......I am looking for an output of 4 rows and 6 variables

Comment: @chinsoon12, this gives 4 rows and 1 RMSPE variables :(.....

Comment: @chinsoon12, Thank you for your answers and suggestions. However in my actual data, the variable names do not have a pattern. I mean they are not suffixed with 1,2,3,4, etc. So something like storing them in a vector may be an option, like actual = c(a1,a2,a4,a4,a5) and pred = c(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) (I would need to add the "" for the names)......thats the reason I was creating a function to pass two vectors but then not sure how to pass them with lapply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you looking for

```
colsToKeep <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5")
colsToW <- c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5")


df1[, Map(function(x,y, w) get(x)(y, w), 
          setNames(rep('RMSPE',length(colsToKeep)), paste("RMSPE", colsToKeep, colsToW, sep = "_")),
          .SD[, ..colsToKeep], .SD[, ..colsToW]),
    by = city]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to be working on my sample data. Note - order of passing colsTokeep and colsToW should be swapped. Could you please confirm on the 3 parameters x,y,w and their link with setNames(). Is it that the 1st parameter in SetNames gets a return of "RMSPE" 5 times which is used in get(x) and the 2nd parameter forms the columns headings. .SD are the inputs for y and w. So finally get(x)(y,w) becomes RMSPE(colsTokeep,colsToW)......right? how does it do it for all columns?

Comment: yes. setNames have the function and the names of the columns, and both SD has the parameters  of the functions, in this particular case y and w

Comment: another option: `df1[, Map(function(x, y) RMSPE(get(x), get(y)), colsToW, colsToKeep), by=city]`

Comment: @fidelin, Thank you!!

Comment: @chinsoon12, Thank you !!